# ¿Como poner botones arriba de un gif en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy intentando poner un gif como fondo de un JFrame con un JLabel y quiero poner unos botones encima del gif de fond, pero los botones no se ven, solo parpadean si paso el mouse por encima de ellos. este es el codigo:

```
private void imagen(){

    ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/inventario/fondo.gif"));
    Icon icoimagen = new ImageIcon(imagen.getImage().getScaledInstance(fondo.getWidth(), fondo.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    fondo.setIcon(icoimagen);
    fondo.setOpaque(true);

}
```

Ese metodo lo mando a llamar desde el constructor de la clase, estoy trabajando en NetBeans.

Comment: Qué tipo de layout utilizas en el JFrame?

Comment: No uso ninguno esta como "Null Layout"

Comment: eso no compila porque según se ve en tu código fondo no ha sido definido. Asegúrate de poner siempre un [mcve], es decir, algo que compile

Answer (score 1):

En el editor de GUI de NetBeans ( [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse) ), da clic derecho sobre los botones y luego selecciona la opción **Move Up**. O clic derecho sobre el JLabel y luego selecciona la opción **Move Down** (opción recomendada).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto lo que haces es agregar el JLabel como último elemento al `ContentPane` del JFrame, y como estos elementos contenidos en el `ContentPane` se pintan de adelante hacia atrás (en profundidad en la pantalla), el JLabel se pintaría debajo de el resto de elementos.